# How to create a not persistent abstract superclass for a persistent class

Tags: inheritance, persistence, abap

I wanted to create an abstract super class for my persistent classes, which provides some functions to query against any other persistent class which is member of that class.

So I tried to add this abstract class as superclass, when I got following error:

> The superclass of a persistent class must be persistent
>
> Message no. OO629

Is there some kind of good workaround? (I mean something diffrent from making an Interface and Copy-Paste the functions into each subclass)

### Here some additional info:

[Here is what I want to do (Try IE if it does not work with chrome or friefox](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-9156)

Short Abstract:

- (I am working in `user`)
- Creating a general function to query against every key.
- Creating a more specific function using the general function to query all the "links" from a join table(`user_has_tag`), filling them into a attribute
- Query the other foreignkey (`tag`) using the general function again.

Here my abstract superclass (with the general function `QUERY_BY_UUID`:

```
CLASS zcl_ps_hrmobject DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  ABSTRACT
  CREATE PUBLIC .

  PUBLIC SECTION.

    METHODS get_uuid
      RETURNING
        VALUE(ro_uuid) TYPE uuid .
  PROTECTED SECTION.

    METHODS query_by_uuid
      IMPORTING
        !ir_agent         TYPE REF TO object
      RETURNING
        VALUE(rt_entries) TYPE osreftab
      RAISING
        cx_os_object_not_found
        cx_os_query_error .
    METHODS get_query
      RETURNING
        VALUE(rr_query) TYPE REF TO if_os_query .
  PRIVATE SECTION.

    CONSTANTS lc_query_method_name TYPE string VALUE 'IF_OS_CA_PERSISTENCY~GET_PERSISTENT_BY_QUERY'. "#EC NOTEXT
    DATA mlr_query TYPE REF TO if_os_query .
ENDCLASS.



CLASS zcl_ps_hrmobject IMPLEMENTATION.


* <SIGNATURE>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | Instance Protected Method ZCL_PS_HRMOBJECT->GET_QUERY
* +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | [<-()] RR_QUERY                       TYPE REF TO IF_OS_QUERY
* +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</SIGNATURE>
  METHOD get_query.
    rr_query = me->mlr_query.
  ENDMETHOD.


* <SIGNATURE>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | Instance Public Method ZCL_PS_HRMOBJECT->GET_UUID
* +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | [<-()] RO_UUID                        TYPE        UUID
* +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</SIGNATURE>
  METHOD get_uuid.
* must be implemented in subclass

    RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE cx_os_no_implementation
*      EXPORTING
*        textid =
*        previous =
      .
  ENDMETHOD.


* <SIGNATURE>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | Instance Protected Method ZCL_PS_HRMOBJECT->QUERY_BY_UUID
* +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | [--->] IR_AGENT                       TYPE REF TO OBJECT
* | [<-()] RT_ENTRIES                     TYPE        OSREFTAB
* | [!CX!] CX_OS_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND
* | [!CX!] CX_OS_QUERY_ERROR
* +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</SIGNATURE>
  METHOD query_by_uuid.
    DATA: lr_query TYPE REF TO if_os_query,
          lr_uuid  TYPE uuid.

    lr_query = me->get_query( ).
    lr_uuid  = me->get_uuid( ).

*TRY.
    CALL METHOD ir_agent->(lc_query_method_name)
      EXPORTING
        i_query = lr_query
*       i_parameter_tab =
        i_par1  = lr_uuid
*       i_par2  =
*       i_par3  =
*       i_subclasses    = OSCON_FALSE
*       i_upto  = 0
*       i_options       = IF_OS_QUERY_OPTIONS=>DEFAULT_OPTIONS
      RECEIVING
        result  = rt_entries.
* CATCH cx_os_object_not_found .
* CATCH cx_os_query_error .
*ENDTRY.


  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: Hi inetphantom, if you want people on stackoverflow to help you, please consider accepting answers to the questions you have already asked.

Comment: @Jagger I do not think that comment is appropriate here. And yes, i accept answers, as long as they solve my problem. Have a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you are confused how to use Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with an interface and a static helperclass.

The interface enforces three getter:

```
get_uuid ( )
get_query ( )
get_query_method_name ( )
```

Now each Element implements this interface.

In the helperclass I now have the Query_by_uuid function I wanted to heritate, which gets a Instance type of that interface (`ir_root_instance`).

Here the function

```
  METHOD QUERY_BY_UUID.
    DATA: lr_query             TYPE REF TO if_os_query,
          lr_uuid              TYPE uuid,
          lv_query_method_name TYPE string.

    lr_query             = ir_root_instance->get_query( ).
    lr_uuid              = ir_root_instance->get_uuid( ).
    lv_query_method_name = ir_root_instance->get_query_method_name( ).

*TRY.
    CALL METHOD ir_agent->(lv_query_method_name)
      EXPORTING
        i_query = lr_query
*       i_parameter_tab =
        i_par1  = lr_uuid
*       i_par2  =
*       i_par3  =
*       i_subclasses    = OSCON_FALSE
*       i_upto  = 0
*       i_options       = IF_OS_QUERY_OPTIONS=>DEFAULT_OPTIONS
      RECEIVING
        result  = rt_entry.
* CATCH cx_os_object_not_found .
* CATCH cx_os_query_error .
*ENDTRY.


  ENDMETHOD.
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Your description sounds like you might want to take a closer look at the methods provided by the generated agent classes and the query service, though.

Comment: I followed a tutorial of Thomas Jung from SAP. I provided the link (and my code) in the question. He does it like this for one class, so I wanted to do (that part where possible) in a superclass.

Comment: From your code, I can't guess what you're trying to do, and I don't have the time to watch a one-hour presentation to determine what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for that, I added a abstract. Absolutley logic you do not have the time for that, should have thought of that. (nobody got just an hour left for "nothing")